# Animate speedometer needle using SCSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, css-animations

I have already checked other links availble here but I am not able to find things suitable for me. I am trying to animate a speedometer here [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpragesh/v3hj9q01/7/) - going from left (red) to right (green). I trying trying to make the needle loop at the end area of the barometer.

I didn't get the expected result. How can I achieve this using only SCSS?

```
totalPercentageCal: number = 40;
```

```
    <div class="speedoMeter" *ngIf="segmentName=='To do' && actionsAssignedToMe_arraylist.length > 0">
         <span class="action-score">Action management score 
            <ion-icon class="score-info-icon" id="score-trigger" name="information-circle-outline">
            </ion-icon>
          </span>
          <ion-row class="speedometerImg">
            <ion-col size="12" class="padZero mt-30 speedometerCol">
              <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/RVfYGWYt/bbc.jpg" class="speedometer-svg" />
              <span class="needle">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/rFCJKxbf/abc.jpg" class="arrow-svg" [style.transform]="'rotate(' + totalPercentageCal * 1.8 + 'deg)'"/>
              </span>
              <ion-row class="needle-frnt-bg">
                <h2 clas

s="percentage">{{totalPercentageCal}}%</h2>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </div>



.speedoMeter{
  padding-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  .action-score{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .speedometerImg{
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
  .speedometerCol{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .percentage{
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%; 
    text-align:center;
  }
  .speedometer-svg{
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
  }
  .arrow-svg{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .needle {
    display: flex;
      left: 39%;
      position: absolute;
       top: 30%;
      transform-origin: bottom;
      z-index: 1;
  }
  .needle-frnt-bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    bottom: -2px;
   h2 {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: 600;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The transform-origin should be on bottom right with this image. The transform on needle of 120 means it will stay on 120deg at the end.

```
.needle {
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    animation: 2s rotate;
    transform: rotate(120deg);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(120deg);
  }
}
```